# insmod custom module fails with message : disagrees about version of symbol

Tags: kernel, version, insmod

I want to make a netfilter conntrack module for myself. So I copy all the source code about netfilter conntrack from kernel source tree to my external directory. It can be insmod after compiled. Then I add some members to the struct nf_conn, and it 's compiled successfully. However, it can't be insmod. The system gives me the message " disagrees about version of symbol ...." .

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: I want to have my own conntrack modules without affect the original kernel proceess. The original conntrack module is kept as before.

Comment: Structure `nf_conn` you have modified used not only by netfilter conntrack module, but also in [other modules](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/ident/nf_conn). If your module uses functions from those modules, you need to recompile them too. (BTW, the symbol shown in "disagree about version" message probably uses given struct).

Comment: Thanks, I have got the solution.   I answered myself.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the file Module.symvers from directory of the modified conntrack modules to the current developing module. For the same function names , it will be used instead of that provided by kernel source tree.

Or modify the Makefile:
obj-y := new_conntrack/ caller/

It will use the new CRC value from new_conntrack/ .
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt